# Changing to a frequently used directory easily

Tags: directory, cd-command

Every time I need to go to a new directory I give the command `cd` and the name of the directory and `ls` to see the contents inside it. Is there any method or command to directly go the directory of my interest without giving the command again and again?

Comment: Is it always the same, specific directory? Is it one of many directories with the same name (e.g. you want a trick for moving into a subdirectory of your current directory  named `foo`)?

Answer (score 2):

A *possible* solution could be to use the `CDPATH` shell variable.  This holds a set of `:`-delimited directory names that the `cd` command will look for directories in.

For example, you may set this variable as

```
CDPATH=".:$HOME/Documents"
```

The `.` at the start ensures that `cd somename` would always try to `cd` to `somename` in the *current* directory if there is a directory in the current directory with that name.

The `$HOME/Documents` means that if there directory name that you use `cd` with is not found in the current directory, then it is looked for in `$HOME/Documents` (the `Documents` directory in your home directory).

This means that you easily could `cd` to the `homework` subdirectory of `$HOME/Documents` from anywhere with

```
cd homework
```

... assuming there is such a directory there and not in the current directory.

The `CDPATH` variable should never be exported!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the full path, you can just go to it:

```
cd /home/user/Documents/homework/
```

Most shells have some sort of <kbd>TAB</kbd> auto-complete.  In bash, you can start typing and <kbd>TAB</kbd> once to autocomplete the directory if there is only one option. If there are several options, <kbd>TAB</kbd> a second-time to get your shell to show you all options.

```
user ~ $ cd D[TAB][TAB]
Desktop/ Documents/ Downloads/
user ~ $ cd D
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your **command history**. There are a couple of easy ways to get started with this:

1. At he command prompt, hit the "up arrow" key to get the previous command, hit it again to back to two commands previous. You can scroll up and down through your entire command history in this way.
2. You can search for previous commands: type `^r` (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>). Then type in a few letters of anything you remember from the command. The history function will search through your previous commands for matches. If you get a match, but it's not the one you wanted, type `^r` again, and it will go to the next earlier command that matches.

There are numerous usage guides online - [this one is fairly good.](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44997/how-to-use-bash-history-to-improve-your-command-line-productivity/). I feel it's important not to take these guides too literally, as there are variations. Trial-and-error has worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use aliases to change directory. I use this to quickly go to my development folder:

`alias devel='cd /mnt/d/devel/'`

Or for your logs:

`alias logs='cd /var/log'`

Answer (score 0):

So, building on the existing answers, we can build a command-line tool - let's call it `cdf` for "cd to frequent directories".

The idea is the following:

1. look at the command history, like [@Seamus pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615953/24308), and identify the most popular directories
2. filter the directories that do not exist or are not relevant (ex: `..`)
3. propose a menu with those directories
4. `cd` to the selected directory

In order for the popularity of directories to be updated, after a successful `cd`, we need keep in mind to manually update the history after moving to the selected directory as the `cd` of step 4 will not be recorded

Here a bash solution to add to your `.bashrc`:

```
## cdf -- cd to frequent directories
function cdf() {
  # Use awk to extract the directories from the history, using null characters as the separator
  DIRS=$(history | tr '\n' '\0' | awk -v RS='\0' '$2 == "cd" && !/\$DIR/ { $1=""; $2=""; sub("^[[:space:]]*", ""); print }' | grep -v -P -C 5 'cd.*$DIR' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 12 | awk '{$1=""; sub("^[[:space:]]*", ""); print }')

  # Filter out directories that don't exist and parent directories
  VALID_DIRS=()
  while IFS= read -r -d '' DIR; do
    if [ -d "$(eval echo "$DIR")" ] && [[ "$DIR" != ".." && "$DIR" != */.. ]]; then
      VALID_DIRS+=("$DIR")
    fi
  done < <(echo "$DIRS" | tr '\n' '\0' )
  
  if (( ${#VALID_DIRS[@]} == 0 )) ; then
    echo "No directories in history."
    return 1
  fi

  # Use select to create a menu of the directories
  PS3="Choose a directory to cd to: "
  select DIR in "${VALID_DIRS[@]}"; do
    if [ -z "$DIR" ]; then
      echo "Invalid choice."
    else
      cd "$(eval echo "$DIR")" && history -s "cd $DIR" # cd and add the cd command to the history
      break
    fi
  done
}
```

This is how the output looks like in real life:

```
~$ cdf 
 1) /home/maybit/junk/code/python/django/getting_started
 2) /home/maybit/Music
 3) /home/maybit/junk/xwiki/xwiki-platform-distribution-flavor-jetty-hsqldb-15.0-rc-1
 [...]
10) /home/maybit/Downloads
Choose a directory to cd to: 1
~/junk/code/python/django/getting_started$
```

You can easily add `ls` after the `cd` in the `select` if that's what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little off-topic, but using [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) as a command-line-ish file manager you can set up as many shortcuts as you want (`shift+b` and enter the name to use as a shortcut) and when needed just hit `b` and enter the shortcut to navigate to.

Delete and add shortcuts from the list (actually just symlinks) as the need arises.

Easier to manage than editing scripts or shell variables and with four the `tabs` that nnn provides I don't even need the shortcuts most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be in a directory to list its contents:

```
ls /usr/share
```

If you set an environment variable (e.g. in /etc/profile `STUFF="/usr/local/share/useful/things"`) then you don't even need remember the path:

```
ls $STUFF
```

The `pushd` is like `cd` but you can return to whence you came with the `popd` command:

```
user@host /etc $ pushd $STUFF
user@host /usr/local/share/useful/things $ pwd
/usr/local/share/useful/things
user@host /usr/local/share/useful/things $ popd
user@host /etc $
```

Or if you start typing the path you can press tab to append the matching entries to the line you are editing. e.g. after setting then typing $STUFF press tab twice and you'll see something like this:

```
user@host ~ $ STUFF=/usr/local
user@host ~ $ $STUFF/
bin/     games/   lib/     php/     share/
etc/     include/ man/     sbin/    src/
user@host ~ $ $STUFF/
```